# Finding the remainder when $1.1!+2.2!+3.3!+ ... +10.10! +2$ is divided by $11!$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Find the remainder when $1.1!+2.2!+3.3!+ ... +10.10! +2$ is divided by $11!$

An attempt: Rearranging:

$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{2.2!}{11}+\frac{3.3!}{11} \cdots +\frac{10.10!}{11}+\frac{2}{11!}$$
$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{2}{11!}+\frac{2.2!}{11}+\frac{3.3!}{11} \cdots +\frac{10.10!}{11}$$
$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{(2+1)2!}{11!}+\frac{3.3!}{11} \cdots +\frac{10.10!}{11}$$
$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{3.2!}{11!}+\frac{3.3!}{11} \cdots +\frac{10.10!}{11}$$
$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{(3+1)3!}{11!}+\frac{3.3!}{11} \cdots +\frac{10.10!}{11}$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{(10+1)10!}{11!}$$
$$\frac{11!+1}{11!}$$

What is the remainder?

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Observe that $$r\cdot r!=(r+1-1)\cdot r!=(r+1)!- r!$$

Do you recognize the [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)? Just set $\displaystyle r=1,2,\cdots,9,10$ and add

Comment: It will lead to $$\frac{11!+1}{11!}$$

Comment: @ManojPandey, yes, the sum will be $\displaystyle 11!+1$ which is $\equiv1\pmod{11!}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k.k!=(n+1)!$$.this summation should be used in your question

Answer (score 0):

To the given expression add and subtract $1!+2!+.......+10!$ so that it becomes:

$$(1+1).1!+(2+1).2!+(3+1).3!+...+(10+1).10!+2-(1!+2!+.......+10!)\\=2!+3!+.....11!+2-(1!+2!+.......+10!)=1+11! $$